# Is there any way to remove the OctoberCMS back-end from a website?

Tags: octobercms

For example, I've made a website using OctoberCMS and its plugins but I want to give to the user a completely new back-end created by me that will still incorporate the back-end part of the used plugins. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

there are mainly three modules and they are interconnected with each other

1. cms
2. backend
3. system

so you can not remove them but you can block `backend access` for the cms or redirect user to your `admin` panel when user try to open `http://site/backend`

because if you remove `backend` site will not work as we need plugin settings and etc.. stuff which is interconnected.

best option would be create one `root-folder` called like `admin etc..` make your admin panel there

when user try to open `http://site/backend` redirect him to `http://site/admin`

for this you need to add some `conditions` in `.htaccess` file

add this to your root .htaccess

```
# white list admin folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/admin/.*
```

crete new .htaccess inside your admin folder and redirect all request to 'index.php' except 'js/css/images' (you can get reference of it from current october cms's `.htaccess`)

now to redirect user to this admin folder and not using `backend` as admin panel 
go to `config/cms.php`

```
'backendUri' => '/admin', //replace /backend to /admin
```

now `/backend` will no longer work and `admin` will point o your admin panel.

> unfortunately you can not remove it compeletly as cms require `backend` to work

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I understand. Option B would be to edit the backend interface. Is there any way to edit it? Remove all the buttons and options the user won't need. Let's say, I want to leave there only the add/edit pages buttons and the backend of the used plugins. Is this possible? Not just to block the butons but remove them completely from the interface. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I've tried to edit the css and add "display:none" to the parts I don't want to see in the backend but that thing is always overwritten by something. Can you please explain me what happens there? Thank you.

Later edit: If i create my own admin and i redirect the user from the site/backend to site/admin, is there any way I can incorporate the back end part of the plug ins in my admin?

Comment: yes you can modify `modules\backend\layouts` all backend layout files are here you can edit them so you can add remove html , add new css(`modules\backend\assets\css`) etc at bottom so your css have higher priority and it will work (now your things will not override by defaults if you write css at very bottom as it will have higher priority)

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you can keep the current backend files as it is.
Use the plugin mentioned below which will help to create a separate theme for backend

https://octobercms.com/plugin/cyd293-backendskin